# Dynamic CollectionView based on inputs

Tags: arrays, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Currently my class that fills my collection view is simple:

```
class Search {
// MARK: - Public API
var className = ""
var tutorCenterName = ""

init(className: String, tutorCenterName: String) {
    self.className = className
    self.tutorCenterName = tutorCenterName
}

// MARK: - Private
static func createSearches() -> [Search]
{
    return [
        Search(className: "AC311", tutorCenterName: "ACELAB"),
        Search(className: "CS280", tutorCenterName: "CIS Sandbox")
    ]
}
}
```

The problem is that createSearches() returns only those hard coded Search objects.  I would like to have the user create Search objects in another class that would then add to this array, eventually creating a list of what the user searched for.  For some reason I cannot get createSearches() to return an array variable, only a hard coded array of Search objects.  Is there a way I can get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `Search` class to keep a list of `search` objects, you could use a class variable, like so:

`static var searches: [Search]`

along with the appropriate class level methods to control access to it.

Comment: could you describe the difference between class level and instance level methods please?  I understand fundamentally what they do but how are they defined differently?

Comment: Class level methods and properties are created with the `static` keyword, like the variable in my example, and the `createSearches` method in your original example.